# How to link Eclipse editor window to Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I'm running into an issue in Eclipse where the editor pane is not linked to the project in the `Package Explorer` window.  For instance, if I click on a project in the package explorer and then open a `Problems` window that is set to `Configure Contents` > uncheck `Show all items` > set `Scope` to `On any element in same project`, it will show any applicable errors or warnings, but as soon as I open one of the class files with an error/warning in it, in the editor pane, the problems list goes blank as the editor pane does not appear to link the active tab to the active project.  Simply clicking the `Package Explorer` window will then repopulate the `problems` tab until focus goes back to the editor window/tab.

This used to work with older versions of Eclipse, but ever since I updated Eclipse, it no longer does this and I don't recall which version it was that I had been using.  I've also downloaded a completely clean copy of Eclipse Luna (latest version) and simply imported the old projects and still the same issue.

Is there any way to change it so the active tab in the editor points to its associated project?  It's quite frustrating having to click the `Package Explorer` window every time I want to look at a list of problems or tasks for a specific project.

Edit: I've narrowed the issue down to minimized windows only and provided an example of the issue below.
[image]
Both windows are restricted to "Show issue on project" rather than showing all issues.  Notice how the "Tasks" window works as intended while the "Problems" window does not.

Comment: Possibly the 'Link with Editor' option in Package Explorer (the two way arrow in the Package Explorer tool bar).

Comment: I tried that and, unfortunately, all that does is expand the tree to the file I'm looking at in the editor.  It still does not make the "problems" window highlight all the project's warnings and errors (heck, it doesn't even highlight the ones in the file I"m looking at), I still have to click the `Package Explorer` to get the problems for the project to show up.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue... sort of.  Apparently, if you minimize the problems tab, then try to access it via the minimized icon for the tab, it loses the correct focusing to tell you what the problems are.  My previous version was setup in exactly the same way and had no issues, so they must have changed something that broke this.  Going to look at submitting this to the Eclipse team, as a bug.